# Big Calendar React Need help for basics

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, react-big-calendar

for my second year of dev my school had the good idea to already gave us a client, the amount of work is just to big so I was thinking using tool to make the work faster.

I use Big Calendar React and can use it, but I can't find a way to add event to this html (I don't even know where it is in my nodes modules)
Same goes to where do I remove the button month or week like I've saw on internet exemples.

I can't find a way or tutorial of how to use all of this does some of you know where I can find that ?

Ive tryed to understand the doc on https://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html but it's just impossible for me.

I wanted the drag and drop addon and wanted to know where I can get input of those resize and drag and drop to update them in the database and finaly wanted to remove at least the month button.

Answer (score 0):

An `event` is nothing but an object in the [events](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/props--events) array. 'Adding' an event to the calendar is as easy as adding a new item to the array. Big Calendar is really just a display control, for putting the calendar and it's events on the page. It is up to the developer to write code for adding/editing/deleting `events` from the calendar. The DnD addon gives some helper functions, but ultimately the developer controls the `events` array.

Side Note: The 'Docs' tab, of the documentation site, gives some very detailed information, as well as a 'Show Code' button at the bottom of most of the examples. I would suggest starting with the [About Our Examples](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html?path=/docs/about-our-examples--page) story.